# XML queries with case insensitive tag

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, xml, xquery

I have a requirement where i want XML tags to be case insensitive in my xml queries.

For example:

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE ( yourXML XML )  

INSERT INTO @myTable SELECT '<z><a><b>1</b><c>2</c></a></z>'
INSERT INTO @myTable SELECT '<Z><A><b>1</b><c>2</c></A></Z>'   

SELECT * FROM @myTable WHERE ( [yourXML].exist('for $x in /z/a where  ( ($x/b[1]) = 1 )  return $x')>0 )
```

Returns output as

```
yourXML
<z><a><b>1</b><c>2</c></a></z>
```

But i want the output to display without considering case of the XML tag. So my desired output should be

```
yourXML
<z><a><b>1</b><c>2</c></a></z>
<Z><A><b>1</b><c>2</c></A></Z>
```

How it can be done?

Comment: The real issue is that in XML, `<Z/>` and `<z/>` are entirely different tags. You really need to deal with your root cause which is a DATA issue, not a problem with how SQL Server is working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use predicates with name tests like this instead of "simple" node steps:

```
/*[lower-case(local-name(.)) = 'z']/*[lower-case(local-name(.)) = 'a']
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM @myTable WHERE ( [yourXML].exist('for $x in /*[lower-case(local-name(.)) = 'z']/*[lower-case(local-name(.)) = 'a'] where  ( ($x/b[1]) = 1 )  return $x')>0 )   does not work and gives error

Comment: SELECT * FROM @myTable WHERE ( [yourXML].exist('for $x in /*[lower-case(local-name(.)) = "z"]/*[lower-case(local-name(.)) = "a"] where  ( ($x/*[lower-case(local-name(.)) = "b"][1]) = 1 )  return $x')>0 )  worked for me

Comment: It seems there is a `<B/>` in your data? Glad you found a solution!

Comment: Is there any option to change xml by which xml tags become no more case-sensitive and i can use query without modifying it.?

Answer (score 4):

Somewhat simpler than the FLWOR version.

```
select *
from myTable
where yourXML.exist('(Z/A,z/a)[(b,B)=1]') = 1
```

Comment: Is there any option to change xml by which xml tags become no more case-sensitive and i can use query without modifying it.?

Comment: @ITresearcher There is no way to turn off case sensitivity in XML in SQL Server that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

Necromancing.

If you land here in search of a solution for a case-insensitive XML nodes function, this is how it goes with XPath:

```
DECLARE @Parameters nvarchar(max)
SET @Parameters = N'<root>
    <language>de</language>
    <LaNgUaGe>FR</LaNgUaGe>
    <LANGUAGE>iT</LANGUAGE>
    <something>else</something>
</root>'

-- XML Parameter 
DECLARE @tParameters AS xml; 
SET @tParameters = CONVERT(xml, @Parameters)
-- SELECT @tParameters 

SELECT P.Tag.value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)') 
FROM @tParameters.nodes('//*[lower-case(local-name(.)) = "language"]') AS P(Tag) 
;
```